# Inverting a list in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I have a list:

```
[(HOUSE, 1), (FRAME, 2), (WATER, 3), (WIND, 4), (CREST, 5)]
```

and I want to invert it like this:

```
[(CREST, 5), (WIND, 4), (WATER, 3), (FRAME, 2), (HOUSE, 1)]
```

How do I do that?

A friend told me that there's a way to invert it but first you need to invert the tuple because there's a function that only "looks" at the first element to sort, and since I'm sorting according to the number after the word, I need to put the number first.

Ex.: `(5, CREST)`

Do I really need to do that? And if I do, what do I have to do next? Because I already have a function that inverts the order of the tuple. Now I need to invert the whole list.

Obs.: The list is a user input.

If there's a way to do it without inverting the tuples, please tell me. Maybe I'm trying to do a simple thing in a difficult way.

And please explain how the code works in a simple way because I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`reverse`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:reverse) (imported from `Prelude`):

```
reverse [(HOUSE, 1), (FRAME, 2), (WATER, 3), (WIND, 4), (CREST, 5)]
-- [(CREST, 5),(WIND, 4),(WATER, 3),(FRAME, 2),(HOUSE, 1)]
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/91ba7fe627a82187)

There's no need to sort and/or invert the tuple in lists.

Answer (score 2):

Its instructive to try and implement it yourself. But here's one way from the prelude:

```
reverse =  foldl (flip (:)) []
```

- flip takes a function and returns the same function with its arguments reversed.
- foldl will interleave a function between all the elements of a list
- ":" is the cons function that will append an item to the head of a list

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the other answers, simply reversing a list does not require inverting your tuples or any kind of sorting at all; you can use the `reverse` function from `Prelude`. However, if you do actually want to *sort* based on the numbers in your tuples, it's a slightly more complicated problem.

The `sort` function from `Data.List` is probably the function your friend was referring to. It compares elements of a list using the `compare` function, and then sorts the list according to that. As your friend noted, the implementation of `compare` for tuples is to compare the first elements of each tuple, and if they're equal, look at the second, etc.

However, there is a more general sorting function from `Data.List` called `sortBy`. It has the type signature:

```
sortBy :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> [a]
```

Essentially, it's the same as `sort`, only instead of calling `compare` to compare two values and determine their ordering, you can specify how it compares values. Since you want to compare these tuples by comparing their second values, the function you want to use is `snd` (returns the second element of a tuple). We now have this:

```
λ> :m + Data.List
λ> let list = [(WATER, 3), (WIND, 4), (CREST, 5), (HOUSE, 1),(FRAME, 2)]
λ> let cmp a b = compare (snd a) (snd b)
λ> sortBy cmp list
[(HOUSE,1),(FRAME,2),(WATER,3),(WIND,4),(CREST,5)]
λ> sortBy (flip cmp) list
[(CREST,5),(WIND,4),(WATER,3),(FRAME,2),(HOUSE,1)]
```

To get the sort in descending order I used the `flip` function from `Prelude`, which simply reverses the order of the arguments of a two-argument function.

As a final note I'll bring up the function `comparing` from `Data.Ord`. Without going into too much detail, its functionality can be fairly easily understood by seeing it used in the same snippet of code:

```
λ> :m + Data.List Data.Ord
λ> let list = [(WATER, 3), (WIND, 4), (CREST, 5), (HOUSE, 1),(FRAME, 2)]
λ> sortBy (comparing snd) list
[(HOUSE,1),(FRAME,2),(WATER,3),(WIND,4),(CREST,5)]
λ> sortBy (flip $ comparing snd) list
[(CREST,5),(WIND,4),(WATER,3),(FRAME,2),(HOUSE,1)]
```

Given a function (call it `f`), `comparing` will return a comparing function that calls `f` on two values first and then compares *those* values. Basically exactly what the function `cmp` did in the first example but more concise and readable.